# Make select options from database

Tags: php

I want to make select options list with data from my database

I did something like this

```
<?php
  if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
          ?>
          <select name="name" class="custom-select">
            <?php

          echo "<option value='1'" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
          ?>
          </select>
          <?php
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
?>
```

I see my output but every data is in seperated "box". I just want list to choose for example options1 or 2.
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the `<select>` element outside the loop.

```
<?php
if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) {
  echo '<select name="name" class="custom-select">';
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
  }

  echo '</select>';
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: How to take data from value? For example I want to select option1 with value 1 or option2 with value2 ? I want to use value number

Comment: @NelsonBiggety it makes rather little sense to assign arbitrary numbers to values coming from a database, you should perhaps rather use the record id from the database as the option value here.

Comment: I got ID value in my database for example is: id 1 name: something1
How to use iD?

Comment: Watch your spaces: `value='1'" . $row['name'] . "'` There is none after `'1'`

Comment: Can i do something like: value=".$row['id']." ??

Answer (score 1):

its happen because you put `<select>` inside loop so it create every time new `<select>`

just put your select outside loop like as follow

```
<select name="name" class="custom-select">
<?php 
while($row = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value='1'" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting select elements inside each loop

```
<select name="name" class="custom-select">
<?php 
        while($row = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>" .$row['name']."</option>";
         }
?>
</select>
```

And watch out for unnecessary single quote  that will break your html:

```
 "'>"
```

Comment: I just tested it and i do not seems to find any bad markup. Can you point out where it does please? @mickmackusa

Comment: @mickmackusa you are absolutely right, answer updated. Thank you!

Comment: You may also notice that the `value` declaration is not needed because it is identical to the option text.  If you read the selected answer, the OP wants the `id` value anyhow.  There is no use editing to duplicate the accepted answer though.

Comment: Yup i know. But it was annoying anyway to leave my answer like that